# CakePHP bake generating auth component user actions

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-bake

I'm sure there is a relatively simple answer. I am trying to use CakePHP 2.0 to bake an application from the command line, and i would like cake to create the basic `AuthComponent` methods for my `user` model. the database table for users is named `users`, which includes the two necessary fields for auth, `username` and `password`.

I've been able to include `AuthComponent` in my `usersController` from bake, but have been unsuccessful at getting it to generate basic `usersController` actions for auth, such as `login()` and `logout()`.

How can I do this? generating this skeleton code will help save a lot of time.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

default bake templates are only for CRUD (create=add, read=index,view update=edit, delete=delete), not for the rest. but it is fairly simple to customize your templates according to your needs.

Although login/logout are one-time-needed methods and don't make any sense to be baked. Its easier and faster to just manually "make" them. For login use the add template as basis, logout doesnt need any view.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, i was just hoping that if I included the Auth component from bake, cake would take a hint a plop all of the AuthComponent specific junk into my project. Thanks.

Comment: lol. it's cake php... everything's technically easy. thanks for the response, though.